# Should I enable "Patrol Read" on SSD drives?

Tags: raid, ssd, lsi, megaraid, megacli

LSI, Intel and Dell RAID controllers (perhaps others) have a "`Patrol Read`" feature to try to spot when a drive is failing before it completely fails.

LSI seems to disable patrol read on SSD by default but allows you to turn it on if desired via `MegaCLi`'s `SupportSSDPatrolRead` option.

Is there any reason why I should NOT turn on patrol read for SSD? Will it cause premature failures? Or is it pointless for SSD?

I am suspicious because of the default disable. But I cannot find documentation anywhere that states why or why not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave it off. It may not be necessary, as quality/enterprise SSDs perform their own wear-leveling and reallocation of bad sectors. The RAID controller's "Patrol Read" is really geared towards the failure modes of mechanical drives.